# Setting values in an array of objects

Tags: typescript, object

How would I add a value to agencyList[0].itemName?

```
export class SelectedItem {
 id: number;
 itemName: string;
 isChecked: boolean;
}

agencyList: SelectedItem[] = [];
```

I am attempting `agencyList[0].itemName = 'agency1';` but getting the error: `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'itemName')`

Comment: Your array is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `agencyList[0]` with an instance of `SelectedItem` first like

```
agencyList[0] = new SelectedItem();
agencyList[0].itemName = "agency1";
```

Presumably you only want to do this in cases where the item has not been initialized already:

```
if (!agencyList[0]) {
    agencyList[0] = new SelectedItem();
}
agencyList[0].itemName = "agency1";
```

And you can use [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) to collapse that into a single line of code:

```
(agencyList[0] ??= new SelectedItem()).itemName = 'agency1'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmJ7AC7wCYEk0FtoG8AoaE6YAewDsIUAnAV1XNoAoBKA407i68pAHQhyAcxYAiAB7i2XEgF850AJboAXNEr0cAI3i1oAXmgBGANxLluAHJgc8DTVrLKIo9HHiL3ZRADCABbIANYYGjrk-PBglO4AZmAgEPAWioS8NNBgIvCUwACeADK+KBoISKgY2PA4ANoAuu4NFoQA9ABUhNm5BcU0tQAMjcaU8ADucIjIaFi47BbdeUUlg-UCVjW29u7iiwUmXoTtrYRtncpx0CwAhHvL-UMcRNx3fSir7qMT5dNVc2ypLo5JZvVbrGx2eA7O4HCzHU6EFivFZDaAAfjRI3GkwqM2qOHYbHBm0h7gA5DCyRYkcDeijGhisd8ppVZjVCet0O5zOkqBAokJRDSevcUGwgA)

Answer (score 1):

Create an object (with the properties defined) and add it to the array

Or

create a blank object then use Object.assign

```js
const agencyList = [{}, {}]
Object.assign(agencyList[0], {itemName: 'agency1' })
```